# Eevee cannot finish a render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-layers

Eevee just won't render my project. I have 2 Terrains in the scene with 6 subsurf divisions and a displacement modifier with image texture for the shape of the terrain and I have 3 nebulae as a background on the sky which are made from principled volume and one more principled volume which is a big box for everything in the scene. I have other objects but I have separated them by render layers so the system can digest it, but it still crashes... When I render with 1 sample it does the job, even though when I click render it still stays blank for 5-6 minutes and I cannot do anything else then magically the render appears, but when I go with 100 samples or more it just won't work it crashes... and I need more than 100 samples because the scene is fairly complex. I tried renderfarm but again the file won't go even through a renderfarm... I need the volumetrics to be at 2px tile size and I think this is clogging the whole render, or the sub divisions on my 2 terrains.

The scene gets to about 9 million faces, which I guess is too much but still I thought it will take time but it just keeps on crashing and not even through a render farm ? How is this even possible

Cannot split the volume of the scene and the terrains because eevee doesn't allow for indirect lights and reflections when you split the scene by render layers.

On the viewport everything runs okay at rendered view but when I try to render it doesn't work...

Is there anyway to go around this problem or I need to sacrifice heavily on quality ?

I spent a whole day + today as well trying to figure out a way to render this ...

Thanks

Comment: Viewport render quality is automatically reduced. I think it is indeed the high volumetrics. There is a reason they allow you to lower the volumetric resolution: so you don’t swamp your RAM and processing time.

Comment: You're right I just fixed it by lowering the sample count on the volumetrics tab from 256 to 100 and it worked like magic. I still keep tile size at 2px and it works. So the main problem was the sample count on the volumetrics.

Comment: all right! Please add your answer to the question so future researchers can find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the sample count on the volumetrics tab fixes the issue